# How to develop our own cordova-plugins?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, plugins, cordova-plugins

Can anyone suggest me to develop our own cordova-plugins and what are the methods to be followed for developing our own plugin?
I have found this example https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/createplugintutorial/ but not clear , can anyone suggest me some other examples and steps to be followed?

Comment: There is a section on cordova.apache.org dedicated to plugin development: [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

As @Beat mentioned, there's the section on plugin development on cordova.apache.org. My experiences on the Microsoft site have been mixed (they tend to add layers on top of what you actually need to create a plugin).

If you're looking for source code examples, you can look at the Apache foundation's mirror on GitHub: [github.com](https://github.com/apache?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=cordova-plugin-&type=&language=). I've filtered out the link to the cordova plugins.